# Explanation of what CDN's do with "cached" resources?

Tags: cdn

I use shared hosting in conjunction with the CDN Cloudflare.  And, my site is definitely faster than before using the CDN.  However, I'd like to have a better understanding of how the CDN and my hosting service interact.  For example, suppose I have an image on a webpage, as well as an external javascript file.  I know that the CDN "caches" these resources.  But, does that mean that instead of transferring the image/javascript from my shared hosting (which would "cost" me bytes transferred each month), that the CDN does it, essentially give me "free" transfer of these resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right if your CDN service provider doesn't charge any data transfer fees (such as free level CloudFlare).

Basically what happened is a user make a request to an asset in your website, if that item is already being cached in your CDN provider's edge node, the item will be served from them.
The only time your server will get a hit is when the asset is not available from the cache or expired.

But this free does come at a cost, there is no free meal and imagine how CloudFlare can survive if simply allow every one to have a free meal.

For most of the free service, there is no performance guarantee so that the cache hit ratio may not be high all the time, CDN provider may only allocate a limited memory to store the cache for free customers, hence there is a relatively higher chance that your assets are not available in the cache.

What's worse is if the content is not available in the cache, then your CDN provider will need to fetch the file to your origin server. Now a direct request from end user to your webpage becomes two indirect request, which obviously will actually increasing the loading time.